# FQL query error 104

Tags: facebook-fql

last week I needed to run a FQL query to return the last wall post of a public page, which is very basic

```
SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 122338662806 limit 1
```

it worked fine, returned an xml schema and I then went to get the message from there. This is all done in the backend of a website, and not a facebook application.

Sunday night though, it stopped returning anything and started giving me:

```
<error_code>104</error_code>
<error_msg>Requires valid signature</error_msg>
```

which after some research, means it wants an access_token. Since this is not a facebook app, is there a way around this, since it's a public page?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the way its done for public pages but adding an access_token worked for me

`SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 122338662806 limit 1&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

this is what facebook says,

`GET /fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`